# Installing multiple mysql as rpm vs tarball

Tags: linux, mysql, fedora, rpm, tar

Which is the suitable way to install multiple mysql servers without affecting the current installation in fedora( rpm or tarball)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MySQL documentation:

[5.3. Running Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-servers.html)